# Timer within Kanban system

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a countdown within google sheets. Basically as a certain bench sends a request and the cell formula in the kanban sheet updates, then I want a time stamp to appear for that and create a difference between Now() and that time stamp to have a countdown timer. This will allow me to put conditional formatting on this cell to alert the operator that they have taken too long to get materials to an area. This code was used to initially set up the time stamp script.

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-5";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Email";
  var timeStampColName = "Date Sent";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

But I want to be able to select specific columns that will be changed to the time stamp instead of just the last column. Also, I am unable to get it to recognize onchange events instead of onedits. I have several google sheets tied together and the script does not recognize an updated cell as actually being edited.

I have even tried other sets of code such as this.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 3 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-05", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

But this still has the issue of not noticing a change within a formula in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation into triggers, I was able to figure out that by creating a event trigger for changes then the script would run. Such a beautiful thing!

Comment: To make your answer complete, just add the relevant code.